# Hyundai Tuscon 2005 repair bill

Tags: maintenance

Replaced both rear struts, alignment, central arm bushing, p/s flush, oil filter change, inspection, headlight, wipers- bill came to $1,312, was that too much?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a little high, but most shops go by the book. That is, they have a list of how long each repair for every car takes in hours (on average), and then they multiply that by how much they charge for labor an hour.

You can usually ask the shop to explain or show you where they get their book hours, and break down the invoice.